# How do you read out numbers in scientific notation in Japanese?

Tags: numbers, mathematics

For example, "5 * 10^80" would be said as "5 times 10 to the power of 80" in English. When translating to Japanese, would I translate all of these operations literally or is there a more widely used idiom like "5 followed by 80 zeroes".

Answer (score 10):

> 5 * 10^80

I think it's read 「ごかけるじゅうのはちじゅうじょう」.

5×10⁸⁰ -- [5]{ご} [×]{かける} [10]{じゅう} の [⁸⁰]{はちじゅうじょう} （5[掛]{か}ける10の80[乗]{じょう}）

Answer (score 6):

In addition to a scientific notation by Chocolate, we use [無量大数]{むりょうたいすう} for such a large power. In [Japanese numeral system](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%91%BD%E6%95%B0%E6%B3%95), we normally remember up to [兆]{ちょう} of 10^12. Normally we expect to pack such a huge power as an unit like "mol" as an avogadro constant. So, we do not normally count it like 無量大数. And in the context of mathematics, we use "log" for it.

The table for 無量大数.

[image]

The table for numeral system.
[image]